# Sorting of list of objects based on multiple parameter

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have a List of Objects `List<Student>`.

```
class Student {
 private String name;
 private Integer age;
 private Integer rank

 public String getName() {
  return this.name;
 }
 public void setName(String name) {
  this.name = name;
 }
 public Integer getAge() {
  return this.name;
 }
 public void setAge(Integer age) {
  this.age = age;
 }
 public Integer getRank() {
  return this.rank;
 }
 public void getRank(Integer rank) {
  this.rank = rank;
 }
}
```

I have to sort List based on rank first, if two students have same rank then based on their age and if their age is same then based on their name.

Can any one help?
Thanks

Comment: Either create a `Comparator<Student, Student>` or have `Student` implement `Comparable<Student>` and then define your comparison logic  in there. Either way, you can then use Java's builtin sorting capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

You can use java8 lambdas

```
List<Student> students = new Arraylist<>();
...
...
...
student.sort()

students.sort(Comparator.comparing(Student::getName).thenComparing(Student::getAge));
```

Comment: I suppose you mean Java8 since lamdas introduced in Java8 and `Student::getName` is illegal in Java7

Answer (score 0):

In java8 you have [.thenComparing(...)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#thenComparing-java.util.Comparator-) method

```
Comparator< Student> studentComparator = Comparator.comparing(student -> student.name);
comparator = comparator.thenComparing(Comparator.comparing(student -> student.age));
comparator = comparator.thenComparing(Comparator.comparing(student -> student.rank));

 // Then pass this comparator in Collections#sort method

Collecions.sort(studentList, studentComparator); Your list will be sorted
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Guava for Java 7 for same use case .

See: https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CommonObjectUtilitiesExplained#compare/compareTo.md